# R: ggplot2 Export to .pdf add results comparing to png? barplot

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I've successfully processed my data A, B and displayed them by barplots and by factors using ggplot2. The problem occurs when I want to export my plots: the same data B, produce the empty plot in basic R plotting and in exporting throught .png (right), however, they produce the "lines" in exporting to .pdf (right). I understand that the reason may be that my B data are actually not equal to 0, and .pdf demonstrate it by  adding "lines" instead of bars in the plots. However, I don't want to report them in this way. Equally, I don't want to use the `free_y_scale`, as the aim of the plotting is mostly to communicate the difference in range of my values for A and B at a first glance.

Please, how can I get rid of these "lines" added by .pdf? Thank you !

```
# export data
png("plot1.png")
pdf("plot1.pdf", height = 6, width = 7, family = "Helvetica") 
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: if you want 0 just plot 0

Comment: Cool @HubertL ! But how? do I have to modify my original data table of it is possible to make it directly in the plot? my final plot consists of 16 subplots due to 2 evaluated factors

Comment: just change your data (and hide the line that does it :-)

Comment: Done ! :)   aaaaaaaaaaaaaa